# Access redux without react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want access to the store (to the dispatch and observe) without the usage of React Components. I've been looking for a couple of hours, with no result.

This is the case. I've created the store in the App root:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import createStore  from './state/store';

let store = createStore();

ReactDOM.render( 
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App>
  </Provider>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I'm happy using the `connect` function offered from `react-redux` when I need to add actions or listen to state changes in a component, but when I want to set some logics outside the component (mainly dispatch) i get stuck.

In short, I want to validate one field. I want to make a `validation.js` file where I can listen for changes from the store, run the validation logics, and then dispatch an action with the eventual error.

As far as the store, it is not global and I'm not using a React Component. Which is the way to get the store to listen for changes and to dispatch actions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I do (after creating my store):

`export const dispatch = store.dispatch`

Then you can call `dispatch` from anywhere in your code (although I pretty much just do it from event handlers).

If you use [Redux-Saga](https://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/) to manage your flow-control, you only rarely need to use `dispatch`, aside from event handlers for direct user inputs, because it wraps dispatching in its `put` API.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should be listening to changes directly from the store, but you would need it in order to dispatch actions.

**Listening to changes**

In `redux` the natural place for you to call this kind of logic would be from the `action` that dispatches the change in the field.

```
export function updateSomeField(value, field) {
    fieldValidator.validate()
    return { type: ActionTypes.UPDATE_SOME_FIELD, field: field, value: value }
}
```

`fieldValidator` can hold a reference to the store in order to get the state he needs in order to perform his logic with `store.getState()`, or get that data from the action as a parameter (with the help of async actions):

```
export function updateSomeField(value, field) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        fieldValidator.validate(getState.myScreen.fields)
        dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.UPDATE_SOME_FIELD, field: field, value: value })
    }
}
```

**Getting the store**

As soon as you create it, you can just provide it to anyone who needs it.
You can either do it by initializing a singleton

```
let store = createStore();
FieldValidator.setInstance(new FieldValidator(store));

// FieldValidator.js
class FieldValidator {
    ...
     static _instance = null;

    static getInstance() {
        return FieldValidator._instance;
    }

    static setInstance(fieldValidator) {
        FieldValidator._instance = fieldValidator;
    }
    ...
}
```

Or by injecting a member

```
let store = createStore();
fieldValidator.store = store;
```